# SetupController for Component Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, ember-cli

I have a component which adds a class for an animation after 5 seconds

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    classNames: ['gears'],
    isVisible: false,

    _startTimer: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function () {
        var _this = this;

        this._visibleTimer = Ember.run.later(this, function () {
            _this._visibleTimer = null;
            _this.set('isVisible', true);
        }, 5000);
    }),

    _endTimer: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function () {
        if (this._visibleTimer) {
            Ember.run.cancel(this, this._visibleTimer);
        }
    })
});

<i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw big {{if isVisible 'fa-counter'}}"></i>
```

My Problem is that in a specific a Route i need to set  `isVisible: true`

I know that in Ember we can access by the route to the controller by [setUpController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) but what if i want to set `isVisible: true` for a Component?

If this is not possible , are there other ways to achieve it? Maybe inside the component itself?

Comment: You can generally override component properties when you create the component so you'd just override isVisible in the correlating template. Have you tried {{my-component isVisible="true"}} ?

Comment: yes absolutely , the problem is that i can not override since the component is in the menu which is persistent in my single app, in this way all the routes pages are affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem that could be resolved through `Ember.Service`. You can go about it in a couple ways, but the more straightforward might be to inject the service into the component and bind `isVisible`.

Something like:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  isVisible: false
});

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  visibility: Ember.inject.service(),
  isVisible: Ember.computed.alias('visibility.isVisible')
});

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  visibility: Ember.inject.service(),

  afterModel() {
    this.set('visibility.isVisible', true);
  }
});
```